# How to show first Public Leaderboards instead of Circles Leaderboards?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

when you are showing a Google Play Game Services LeaderBoard with this code:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), "333333assad87asd"), 1);
```

It's first showed the "circles" leaderboard. I want to show first the "Public" leaderboard.

Is that possible?

Comment: any solution of that issue ?

Comment: None whatsoever ? I was thinking to programmatically tap on the social button, but I can't figure out how to listen for the end of the show leaderboard activity

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. The leaderboard activity controls the circles and public preference. You only have access to the intent to the activity so you can't modify this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, there is a way to show the public variant first. Spent quite some time to find out, but you need to build the "*intent*" with the proper arguments

```
   int showAllTime = LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME;
   int showPublicLb = LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC
   Intent leaderboardIntent = Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(apiClient, menta.getString(R.string.lb_id), showAllTime, showPublicLb);
```

Comment: LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC not working for me. is this a bug or is it due to testing mode?